# SAP B1 Error: 'Item - Can't set value on item because the item can't get focus. [66000-153]'

Tags: sapb1

I am using SAP B1 Studio to make an 2 edittexts with choose from lists for CardCode and CardName. I keep getting the error 'Error: 'Item - Can't set value on item because the item can't get focus.  [66000-153]' after I make a selection from any of the 2.

What could be wrong?

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
this.txtCCode = ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)(this.GetItem("txtCCode").Specific));
txtCCode.ChooseFromListAfter += txtCCode_ChooseFromListAfter;
this.txtCName = ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)(this.GetItem("txtCName").Specific));
txtCName.ChooseFromListAfter += txtCName_ChooseFromListAfter;

private void txtCCode_ChooseFromListAfter(object sboObject, SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg pVal)
        {
            try
            {
                SAPbouiCOM.ISBOChooseFromListEventArg oCFLEvento = (SAPbouiCOM.ISBOChooseFromListEventArg)(pVal);
                string sCFL_ID = oCFLEvento.ChooseFromListUID;
                SAPbouiCOM.DataTable dt = oCFLEvento.SelectedObjects;               
                txtCName.Value = dt.GetValue("CardName", 0).ToString();
                txtCCode.Value = dt.GetValue("CardCode", 0).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Application.SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Error: '" + ex.Message + "'", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
            }
        }

        private void txtCName_ChooseFromListAfter(object sboObject, SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg pVal)
        {
            try
            {
                SAPbouiCOM.ISBOChooseFromListEventArg oCFLEvento = (SAPbouiCOM.ISBOChooseFromListEventArg)(pVal);
                string sCFL_ID = oCFLEvento.ChooseFromListUID;
                SAPbouiCOM.DataTable dt = oCFLEvento.SelectedObjects;
                txtCCode.Value = dt.GetValue("CardCode", 0).ToString();
                txtCName.Value = dt.GetValue("CardName", 0).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Application.SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Error: '" + ex.Message + "'", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if everything is properly bound to the editText and the ChooseFromList is configured,  i would try removing the below from your first method:

```
 txtCCode.Value = dt.GetValue("CardCode", 0).ToString();
```

as it should automatically fill in.

some other possibles:

try setting string instead of value

```
    txtCCode.String =
```

try setting another item to active before setting value

```
   myOtherControl.Active = True
```

Try Setting the value in the dbDatasource:

```
  Dim oDBDataSource As SAPbouiCOM.DBDataSource = form.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item("OCRD")
  oDBDataSource.SetValue("CardCode", 0, dt.GetValue("CardCode", 0))
```

Comment: ah shame,  if you take both  txtCName.Value &    txtCCode.Value   out of both methods,  do you still get the error?

Comment: Edited to show more code. Yes, removed the lines from both methods.

Comment: added a few more things to try :)

Comment: Lol, last one gives error: Error: 'Item - The item is not a user-defined item  [66000-8]'. Second error too. I will keep at it.

Comment: Got it working with DBDatasource, plus fixed another form problem.

Comment: awesome! glad to hear that :)